# Jquery stop animation after 3 secounds and run again after 30 seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval, bounce

i want to make a div bounce 3 times after every 30 secounds, it will be a shopping cart checkout reminder, that is fixed positioned to the right side of the screen, it should bounce three times, then stop for 30 secounds, and then bounce 3 times again...and soon. Currently i used animate class because i  didn't get bounce working when i had fixed positioning..or i think this was the problem. Anyways, here is the code.:

Currently it just keeps on bouncing, it dosen't stop after 3 seconds, and how to make it start bouncing again after 30 seconds?

```
var baloon = $('.checkout');
function runIt() {
    var intID = setInterval(function() {
    baloon.animate({width:'+=4'}, 500);
    baloon.animate({width:'-=4'}, 500);
    }, 1000);
}

runIt();




<div class="checkout"> 
 <img src="img/checkout.png" alt="checkout"> 
 </div>


.checkout{
    width:26px;
    height:114px;
    top:50%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;


}
```

Comment: You did not provide a problem statement. What is not working as you expect?

Comment: Currently it just keeps on bouncing, it dosen't bounce for 3 secounds and then stop and then bounce again after 30 secounds, it just keeps on bouncing atm

Comment: Well you are running the animate code every second.

Comment: Can you use CSS3 animations or you really need to do it using Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be expecting this

```
var baloon = $('.checkout');
function runIt() {
    var intID = setInterval(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            baloon.animate({width:'+=4'}, 500);
            baloon.animate({width:'-=4'}, 500);
        }
    }, 30000);
}

runIt();
```